# Remove NuGet packages from all projects

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

Every time I create a new project, NuGet is adding a ton of packages that I don't want or need. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS 2012, but somehow these packages keep coming back.

How do I completely remove them? If I uninstall NuGet, I get an error "NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop, Version=*, Culture=neutral ...

I then install NuGet, and all the old packages come back. I have no idea where this is being stored (registry?) but if I uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio, these should not be coming back.

Edit: I think I may have figured it out, but need confirmation. When I create a new, empty WebApplication, the packages are not added automatically. If I create a new, empty "Telerik MVC 4 Web Application", then I get the error shown in the picture below. I have set NuGet Package Manager to Allow NuGet to download missing packages and Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio, but I still get the error.

[image: Package Error]

Edit/Solution: It turns out to be a problem with Telerik. I got this from support:

> Is seems that you have ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 installed.
>   Currently this update is not supported by our project templates. Until
>   we provide a support for ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 I suggest you
>   convert an existing ASP.NET MVC Application to a Telerik UI for
>   ASP.NET MVC Application

This seemed to work.

Comment: Is this happening to a single project? In that case, I suggest editing the .csproj file.

Comment: No. I can remove from a single project. The issue is when I create a new blank project, a ton of packages get included. I then have to remove them. I don't know where the defaults are being picked up from, so I can delete / disable them.

Answer (score 0):

The default list of NuGet packages are listed in the project templates.

You can find the templates here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033
```

For example, if you choose MVC 4 Empty Web Application, the default packages are in the *EmptyMvcWebApplicationProjectTemplate.11.cshtml.vstemplate* file:

```xml
    <packages repository="registry" keyName="AspNetMvc4VS11" isPreunzipped="true">
        <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" skipAssemblyReferences="true" />
        <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" skipAssemblyReferences="true" />
        <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20715.0" skipAssemblyReferences="true" />
        <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" skipAssemblyReferences="true" />
        <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" skipAssemblyReferences="true" />
        <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes" version="1.0.0" skipAssemblyReferences="true" />
        <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" skipAssemblyReferences="true" />
        <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" skipAssemblyReferences="true" />
        <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" skipAssemblyReferences="true" />
        <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" skipAssemblyReferences="true" />
        <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" skipAssemblyReferences="true" />

    </packages>
```

BTW: These packages are actually needed since MVC4+ is now installed entirely via NuGet.

Anyway, you can explore the other templates there and edit the *.vstemplate* files to add or remove the default packages.

For more information, look here:

https://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/packages-in-visual-studio-templates
http://www.xavierdecoster.com/update-project-template-to-latest-nuget-packages

Hope this helps.

Comment: But why do I get the error and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Well the Telerik template is trying to install those packages. Did you check to see if they are present in the *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Packages* folder?

Comment: It is empty, so how do I recreate/rebuild it?

Comment: I created a list of all the packages that I have in that folder. Save https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kiliman/11269904/raw/b58deb46f000cf26cf120055b13433d3da287538/packages.config in the *Packages* folder. Once saved, open a command prompt and from that folder type `nuget install packages.config` This will download all the packages. After it's finished downloading, you need to copy the *.nupkg* files from each folder to the *Packages* folder. You can do that by typing `for /r %n in (*.nupkg) do copy %n .`  Hope this helps.